# How to kill all processes younger than

Tags: command-line, killall

I know for `killall` command with `-y` argument and process name.
But I need command to kill all processes younger than some time, without knowing their names.
Something like:

```
killall -y 20m *
```

Comment: I tried killall -y 20m -r (.*?) and it actually killed some processes older than 20 min. Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Try `killall -y 5m -i -r ".*"` or `killall -y 5m -r ".*"`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
 killall -y 5m -i -r ".*"
```

Or use a combination of `ps` and `kill`:

```
kill $(ps -eo pid,etimes | awk '{if ($2 < 300) { print $1}}')
```

First we find the id of process that are running less than of 5 minutes using:

```
ps -eo pid,etimes | awk '{if ($2 < 300) { print $1}}'
```

Then we kill them using `kill`.

<sub>Base of command comes from [here](https://serverfault.com/a/773750/361399).</sub>

Comment: First one with -i argument shows that it start killing all processes, starting from pid 1 (systemd). Second one is too long for me because i want to use it to quickly kill some processes that slows down computer or make it freeze, most of the time from terminal accessed with ctrl+f4/5/6... (don't know its name).